# How to filter data between two dates using eloquent laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to filter data between two dates in laravel. I have table with column date where date is stored in Y-m-d format.

```html
$total = App\Models\Data::where('age_id',$age->id)
            ->where('nationality',$nationality)
            ->when(isset($to), function($q){
                $q->whereBetween('dateTime',[$from,$to]);
            })->when(!isset($to), function($q){
                $q->where('dateTime',$from);
            })
            ->sum('count');
```

My condition is that $to sometimes can be null. But whereBetween requires both $from and $to for it to work. And whereIn fetch data of $from and $to but not between $from and $to. If only $from is filled I want to filter data on that requested date. And if $from and $to is filled I want to filter data between $from and $to and perform count on those data. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data = App\Models\Data::where('age_id',$age->id)
            ->where('nationality', $nationality)
            ->when(isset($to), function($q) use($from, $to){
                $q->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to]);
            })
           ->when(!isset($to), function($q) use($from){
                $q->whereDate('date', $from);
            })
          ->get();
```

Comment: instead of get can I use sum because i am summing here

Answer (score 1):

For this you can assign a value for `$to` when is null, for example:

```
if (!$to) {
    $to = now();
}

$data = Data::whereBetween('date',[$from, $to])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent comes with a `when()` function that can choose when parts of the query need to be executed.

```
$data = Data::when(isset($to), function($q){
            $q->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to]);
        })->when(!isset($to), function($q){
            $q->whereDate('date', $from);
        })->get();
```

Comment: I am getting undefined variable $from now

Comment: I have edited my function, can you please see that

Comment: use this  if($request->from){
            $dates=$this->dateFilter($request->from,$request->to);
            $from=$dates[0];
            $to=$dates[1];
        }

Comment: where should I use that